# Lucene index file gets corrupted by using 2 nodes

Tags: lucene

The lucene index file gets corrupted during loadtest of 15 min :-  creating the index with 2 nodes with 60 cocurrent users. 
I am using Lucene 3.6 version. The index is created in NFS.
Please let me know does lucene create index works on multiple nodes with NFS.

The error exception is org.apache.lucene.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out.

Regards,
Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two (or more) writers simultaneously to update a Lucene index.
It's just not supported by Lucene.

The way this is implemented by Lucene via the file system. Any writer that wishes to write to the index should create a file named `write.lock`. If this file already exists, it can wait, but eventually will time out. If you try to make some workaround (Like deleting the file), your index might become corrupt.

That's the meaning of your exception.